# PowerShell Remove-Item not waiting

Tags: powershell, filesystems, synchronous, ntfs

If have this piece of code

```
if(Test-Path -Path $OUT) 
{ 
    Remove-Item $OUT -Recurse 
}
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $OUT
```

Sometimes it works, but sometimes the New-Item line produces a *PermissionDenied  ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError* error. Which, I assume, means that the previous Remove-Item was not completely performed yet and the folder cannot be created because it still exists.

If I insert a sleep there

```
if(Test-Path -Path $OUT) 
{ 
    Remove-Item $OUT -Recurse 
    Start-Sleep -s 1
}
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $OUT
```

then it works always. 
How can I force Remove-Item to ensure that the folder is really removed?
Or maybe I miss something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Remove-Item` command has a [known issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/199921/force-remove-files-and-directories-in-powershell-fails-sometimes-but-not-always).

Try this instead:

```
if (Test-Path $OUT) 
{ 
    # if exists: empty contents and reuse the directory itself
    Get-ChildItem $OUT -Recurse | Remove-Item -Recurse
}
else
{
    # else: create
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $OUT
}
```

**Note:**

- The `Get-ChildItem` command only finds *non-hidden* files and subdirectories, so emptying out the target directory may not be complete; to include hidden items too, add `-Force`.
- Similarly, add `-Force` to `-RemoveItem` to force removal of files that have the *read-only* attribute set.

  - Without `-Force`, emptying may again be incomplete, but you'll get non-terminating errors in this case; if you want to treat them as terminating errors, add `-ErrorAction Stop` too.

Answer (score 10):

*Update*: **Starting with (at least <sup>[1]</sup>) Windows 10 version `20H2`** (I don't know that Windows *Server*  version and build that corresponds to; run `winver.exe` to check your version and build), the `DeleteFile` Windows API function now exhibits *synchronous* behavior, which **implicitly solves the  problems with PowerShell's `Remove-Item` and .NET's `System.IO.File.Delete` / `System.IO.Directory.Delete` (but, curiously, *not* with `cmd.exe`'s `rd /s`).**

---

**`Remove-Item -Recurse` is unexpectedly *asynchronous***, ultimately because the **Windows API methods for file and directory removal are inherently asynchronous** and `Remove-Item` doesn't account for that.

This *intermittently, unpredictably* manifests in one of two ways:

- Your case: recreating a removed directory immediately after removal can fail, because the removal may not have completed yet by the time re-creation is attempted.
- More typically: Removing a nonempty directory itself can fail, if removal of a subdirectory or file hasn't completed yet by the time an attempt is made to remove the parent directory - this is demonstrated in the [ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/q/199921/176094) marsze links to.

A **potential workaround** is to *reuse* an existing directory by *emptying* it - instead of deleting and *recreating* it.

However, ***emptying* the directory with `Get-ChildItem $OUT -Recurse | Remove-Item -Recurse` is *also* susceptible to intermittent failures**, though likely less often.

The problem not only affects PowerShell's `Remove-Item`, but also `cmd.exe`'s `rd /s` as well as .NET's `[System.IO.Directory]::Delete()`:

As of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core 6.2.0-preview.1 / `cmd.exe` 10.0.17134.407 / .NET Framework 4.7.03056, .NET Core 2.1, **neither `Remove-Item`, nor `rd /s`, nor `[System.IO.Directory]::Delete()` work reliably**, because they **fail to account for the asynchronous behavior of the Windows API file/directory-removal functions**:

- [PowerShell Core bug report](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8211)
- [`cmd.exe` bug report](https://github.com/Microsoft/console/issues/309)
- [.NET Core bug report](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/33603)

For a **custom PowerShell function** that provides a **reliably synchronous workaround**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53561052/45375).

---

<sup>[1] I've personally verified that the issue is resolved in version `20H2`, by running the tests in [GitHub issue #27958](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27958) for hours without failure; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60512798/45375) suggests that the problem was resolved as early as version `1909`, starting with build `18363.657`, but [Dinh Tran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4125534/dinh-tran) finds that the issue is *not* resolved as of build `18363.1316` when removing large directory trees such as `node_modules`. I couldn't find any official information on the subject.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

For completeness' sake: You can also use the safe and fast .NET methods:

```
if ([System.IO.Directory]::Exists($OUT)) {
    [System.IO.Directory]::Delete($OUT, $true)
}
[System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory($OUT)
```

**Note:**

Depending on where you get the value of `$OUT` you might want to convert it to a full path first to make sure the .NET methods remove the correct directory (see @mklement0`s comment):

```
$fullPath = Convert-Path $OUT
```

Comment: Nice alternative, but I strongly suggest passing `(Convert-Path $OUT)` rather than just `$OUT`, because the .NET framework's notion of the working directory typically differs from PowerShell's, so with a relative path in `$OUT` the
target directory may not be found or, worse, a different directory may get deleted.

Comment: I use `[System.IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory((Get-Location).Path)` in many of my custom cmdlets which is extremely useful when interacting with any dlls.

Comment: That is fine if you know you're the only runspace in the process (which is typically true in an interactive shell); the possibility of multiple runspaces is the reason why the directories aren't synced to begin with - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3428. Note that it's better to use `.ProviderPath` rather than `.Path`, because `.Path` can be based on _PS drives_, which .NET is unaware of.

Comment: @mklement0 All true. Nevertheless, I typically choose to ignore such advanced considerations for edge cases, for simplicity, just as I don't bother to make all of my classes perfectly threadsafe. If OP struggles with removing a directory he'll surely not be doing very advanced stuff with his scripts.

Comment: As it turns out, `[System.IO.Directory]::Delete()` is buggy too: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/33603

Answer (score 2):

If you type `Get-Help Remove-Item -Detailed` you'll see:

> ```
> Example 4: Delete files in subfolders recursively
> PS C:\>Get-ChildItem * -Include *.csv -Recurse | Remove-Item
>
> This command deletes all of the CSV files in the current folder and all subfolder recursively.
> ```
>
> Because the Recurse parameter in Remove-Item has a known issue, the
>   command in this example uses Get-ChildItem to get the desired files,
>   and then uses the pipeline operator to pass them to Remove-Item .

Do what specification recommends:

```
if(Test-Path -Path $OUT) 
{ 
    Get-ChildItem $OUT -Recurse | Remove-Item
}
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $OUT
```

Comment: The bug you're referencing is a different one; it relates to the `-Include` parameter, which does not come into play here. Your workaround doesn't delete the target directory itself, so if you want to call `New-Item` unconditionally without causing an error, you must add `-Force` to it. `-Recurse` should be added to `Remove-Item`, because you'll otherwise get a confirmation prompt for every subdir in the target directory's subtree.

Comment: To make it clearer that the referenced bug is unrelated: the`-Recurse` parameter's description in the [same help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-6) states more explicitly (emphasis added), "_When it is used with the Include parameter_, the Recurse parameter might not delete all subfolders or all child items. This is a known issue. "