# Powershell script not always renaming a directory with Rename-Item

Tags: windows, powershell, file, deployment, automation

I use a powershell script to automatically deploy changes to a C# WPF application across a series of devices at my workplace. The way we used to handle deployment was to purge the `Release` directory of all items, then copy everything from the `Release_upcoming` directory to the `Release` directory before finally deleting the `Release_upcoming` directory entirely. But we changed the script to simply delete and rename the directories instead, which does save some time in the deployment process when it works. However, we've now been running into an inconsistent issue with the deployment process where sometimes a device won't rename the `Release_upcoming` directory to `Release` during the script like it should, yet everything else works as intended. It always deletes the old directory like it is supposed to, just once in a blue moon it fails to rename the new directory. Since the issue is inconsistent, I haven't been able to do much to fix the issue, and I can't seem to find anything else about this online. All of our devices are running Windows 10 build 10.0.19045 (aka 22H2).

Since it works most of the time, my guess was that this is a race condition, where there is a handle on either the `Release_upcoming` directory or the old `Release` directory when the `Release_upcoming` directory is to be renamed, but adding a sleep statement to wait for handles to be released did not seem to help as the issue continued to occur inconsistently. Also, using a sleep statement just feels wrong.

**EDIT:**

After trying out a new script, the issue still appears to be occurring. Using the following code, we had 2 devices fail to deploy out of 15. What was in the directories on these devices was just the `Release_upcoming` folder, meaning the original `Release` folder was successfully renamed and deleted. And judging from the error logged, `The system cannot find the file specified`, it would appear that it can't find the `Release_upcoming` folder - even though it tested for it at the beginning of the if statement?

```
try {
    if (Test-Path $UpcomingReleasePath) {
        $DeployTimestamp = (Get-Item $UpcomingReleasePath).CreationTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
        $ReleaseTimestamp = (Get-Item $ReleasePath).CreationTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
        "${Timestamp} from $(whoami) flagging the current release for deletion which was created at ${ReleaseTimestamp}..." | Out-File -FilePath $DeployLogPath -Append -Force
        Rename-Item -Path $ReleasePath -NewName $OldReleasePath
        "${Timestamp} from $(whoami) deploying the newest release which was created at ${DeployTimestamp}..." | Out-File -FilePath $DeployLogPath -Append -Force
        Rename-Item -Path $UpcomingReleasePath -NewName $ReleasePath
        "${Timestamp} from $(whoami) removing the old release which was created at ${ReleaseTimestamp}..." | Out-File -FilePath $DeployLogPath -Append -Force
        Remove-Item $OldReleasePath -Force -Recurse
    }
} catch {
    "Error:"
    Write-Host $_
    "${Timestamp} from $(whoami) encountered an error: $_" | Out-File -FilePath $DeployLogPath -Append -Force
}
```

The logs for the failed deploy are below as well if that helps at all:

```
flagging the current release for deletion which was created at 2023/11/22 09:50:17...
deploying the newest release which was created at 2023/12/01 09:41:22...
removing the old release which was created at 2023/11/22 09:50:17...
encountered an error: This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53508169/45375) is a potential cause, albeit only if you're running an old version of Windows 10 or below.

Comment: @mklement0 - just checked and all of our devices are running Windows 10 build 10.0.19045 (aka 22H2) - so we should be up-to-date enough where that issue should be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

```
Rename-Item -Path $ReleasePath -NewName "$ReleasePath-toRemove"
Rename-Item -Path $UpcomingReleasePath -NewName $ReleasePath
Remove-Item -Path "$ReleasePath-toRemove" -Force -Recurse
```

Renaming should be quite faster than deleting, so it should resolve any racing condition on the original directory, letting you replace it with the new one ASAP and then leaving you with all time in the world to delete the original directory

As alternative: have you thought about using symbolic links?

Comment: That makes sense, and I feel a little stupid having not thought of that yet. I can give it a try and see if it solves the issue!
Although, I'm not really seeing how symbolic links would be useful in this situation, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: A Symbolic Link would be useful because you'd only need to change its Target

Example:

You app\program\whatever targets /release
/release is a symbolic link, which in turn targets /release-2022
When you upload /release-2023 you only need a single command, `New-Item -Target /Release-2023 -Path /release -Force` to replace it on the spot, while keeping both versions around. Very useful if there is ever necessity of switching back and\or back-and-forth... or even to a completely different target directory(es: /experimental/Necessary)
But I think it needs Admin rights

Comment: I appreciate the writeup on that, it makes sense and I tried it out yesterday but it does indeed require admin rights to run through PS, which the automated deploy script does not have sadly.